# MySQL - query with INNER JOIN + WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join, where-clause

```
SELECT `views`.* FROM `views` 
    INNER JOIN memberships ON memberships.second_id = views.user_id 
    WHERE (memberships.user_id = 1 OR views.user_id = 1)
```

I have this MySQL query - my problem is, that the second part of `WHERE` clause doesn't work, are fetched only rows, which equals `memberships.user_id = 1`, but already not `OR views.user_id = 1`.

Why not? What's wrong?

Comment: are there definately records in the view table that (when joined) match the query ?

Comment: perhaps the mysql operator AND instead of OR ... anyway your question is a bit confused, specially "are fetched only rows" ..

Comment: Please revise the explanation because it is not yet clear.  Maybe you should produce a minimal example of the schema and sample data in the tables, plus what you get versus what you expect.  You probably only need a few (1-4) rows in `views` and a few (1-4) rows in `memberships` to show your problem.

Comment: guys, I tried to use `LEFT` instead of `INNER` JOIN and it works...

Comment: @user984621 then you have no records in table `views` where `memberships.second_id = views.user_id` and `views.user_id = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you are joining on `memberships.second_id` maybe it should be `memberships.user_id=views.user_id` because if the condition `memberships.user_id=1` is true, the views.user_id is equal to memberships.second_id and that second_id may not be equal to 1

Comment: I tried to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` and it looks it works, but I am not very sure, if it's a right way

Comment: sure, instead of `1` should be `views.user_id` - I copied the query fro terminal window, where are the numbers instead of variables.